# Filling a table or list with data from SQL (entity framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I cant get data to my table/list, I was trying to follow few videos and answers from stack overflow, but no data shows in tables...

> This is my "Klubovi" class, "KluboviContext" class and "KluboviController":

"Klubovi" class, "KluboviContext" classes are in Models.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace filltabletest.Models
{
    public class Klubovi
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string ImeKluba { get; set; }
        public virtual string KratkoIme { get; set; }
        public virtual string Sport { get; set; }
        public virtual string League { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using filltabletest.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace filltabletest.Models
{
    public class KluboviContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Klubovi> KluboviPkg { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using filltabletest.Models;

namespace filltabletest.Controllers
{
    public class KluboviController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Klb/
        private KluboviContext db = new KluboviContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var KluboviItems = db.KluboviPkg;
            return View(KluboviItems.ToList());
        }

    }
}
```

---

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<filltabletest.Models.Klubovi>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") </p> <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImeKluba)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.KratkoIme)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sport)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.League)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImeKluba)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KratkoIme)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sport)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.League)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr> }
```

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="KluboviContext" connectionString="Data Source=ZWERINJAK;Initial Catalog=OkladeNEW2;User ID=sa;Password=sa" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Klubovi Db:
[Image:Klubovi db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPgo6.png)

Result: 
[Image: Result from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU7d7.png)

Can someone please help me resolve what to do?

Comment: "@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImeKluba)" <- it's an enumerable, displayName won't work if model is enumerable.

Comment: And You don't have <table></table> clause

Comment: @MajkeloDev, Yes it will.

Comment: Check the value of `var KluboviItems` in the controller. You do not appear to be getting any items.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Rly ? Didn't know it's smart enough to auto resolve this. :)

Comment: @MajkeloDev, Yes, it uses [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{``0}},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}}%29)

Comment: Yes, I dont get any items in var KluboviItems...

Comment: @StephenMuecke Interesting. Good to know, thanks :)

Comment: You are not setting in the context which connection should it use...

Comment: public KluboviContext() : base("KluboviContext"){}